# insert multiple row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

i try to insert multiple row in my database, that image not save to folder and
i get this error

> Blockquote ArrayArrayYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Chrysanthemum.jpg'), ('Hydrangeas.jpg')', '('Chrysanthemum.jpg'), ('Hydrangeas.j' at line 1

this is my code :

```
$hopid = $_POST[photo_hop_id];
$title = $_POST['photo_name_id'];

if(!is_array($title)) {
    $title = array();
}

$titleds = "('" . implode("'), ('", $title) . "')";

$tmp_file = $_FILES['ne_photo_image']['tmp_name'];
$file = $_FILES['ne_photo_image']['name'];  

if(!is_array($tmp_file)) {
    $tmp_file = array();
}
if(!is_array($file)) {
    $file = array();
}

$sementara = "('" . implode("'), ('", $tmp_file) . "')";
$filed = "('" . implode("'), ('", $file) . "')";    

$tmp_file1 = $_FILES['fe_photo_image']['tmp_name'];
$file1 = $_FILES['fe_photo_image']['name']; 

if(!is_array($tmp_file1)) {
    $tmp_file = array();
}
if(!is_array($file1)) {
    $file = array();
}

$sementara1 = "('" . implode("'), ('", $tmp_file) . "')";
$filed1 = "('" . implode("'), ('", $file) . "')";   

if(!move_uploaded_file($sementara, 'image/' . $filed)) {
    echo $_FILES["ne_photo_image"]["error"];
}

if(!move_uploaded_file($sementara1, 'image/' . $filed1)) {
    echo $_FILES["fe_photo_image"]["error"];
}

$y = "INSERT INTO photo VALUES (null, '".$filed."', '".$filed1."', '".$hopid."', '".$titleds."')";
$z = mysql_query($y) or die (mysql_error());
if($z) {
    $msg = "Data sudah ditambahkan";
}
else {
    $msg = "Data tidak bisa dimasukkan";
}

echo print_r($y);
```

and this is my form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table border="0"cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width= "100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Hop Name :<?echo "$data[hop_name]"?>
                <input type='hidden' name='photo_hop_id' value='<?echo"$data[hop_id]"?>'>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <table border="0"cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width= "100%">
            <tr>
                <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width= "50%"> 
                    Near End Site Name : <?echo "$data[ne_site_name]" ?>
                    </br>
                    Near End Site Id : <?echo "$data[ne_site_code]" ?>
                </td>
                <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width= "50%"> 
                    Far End Site Name : <?echo "$data[fe_site_name]" ?>
                    </br>
                    Far End Site Id : <?echo "$data[fe_site_code]"?>
                </td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width= "50%"> 
                    <?  $pm1= mysql_query("SELECT photo_name FROM photo_name WHERE photo_name_id = 1");
                    $dpm1 = mysql_fetch_array ($pm1);echo"$dpm1[0]" ?> 
                    <input type='hidden' name='photo_name_id[]' value='<?echo"$dpm1[0]"?>'> :  
                    <input type="file" name="ne_photo_image[]">
                </td>
                <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width= "50%"> 
                    <?echo "$dpm1[0]"?> : <input type="file" name="fe_photo_image[]">
                </td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width= "50%"> 
                    <? $pm1= mysql_query("SELECT photo_name FROM photo_name WHERE photo_name_id = 2");
                    $dpm1 = mysql_fetch_array ($pm1);echo"$dpm1[0]" ?> 
                    <input type='hidden' name='photo_name_id[]' value='<?echo"$dpm1[0]"?>'> :  
                    <input type="file" name="ne_photo_image[]">
                </td>
                <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width= "50%"> 
                    <?echo "$dpm1[0]"?> : <input type="file" name="fe_photo_image[]">
                </td>
            </tr>   
        </table>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="insert" />
</form>
```

many thanks for help

Comment: Have you tried echoing `$y` to check the query populated from the code?

Comment: yes i echoing $y and i got this:  INSERT INTO photo VALUES (null, '('')', '('')', '', '('')')1

Comment: How come 99% of all problematic code on SO is completely unreadable?

Comment: @Codemonkey what do you mean?

Comment: @MeijuNainggolan: I mean that your code is messy, poorly indented and absolutely void of any helpful comments. I don't mean any offence, but you really should clean up your code making issues much easier to spot.

Comment: @Codemonkey means that person who wrote this code did it completely unprofessional. Will you be able to maintain such code after one year? I don't think so

Comment: @Codemonkey i m not a pro, i m just the newbie, if i am pro i never asking in here

Comment: @MeijuNainggolan: You don't have to be a professional programmer to keep your code well formatted. I've prettified the code in your question for you. Please try to at least indent your code properly before you have other people read it in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes clearly from this line :

```
$y = "INSERT INTO photo VALUES (null, '".$filed."', '".$filed1."', '".$hopid."', '".$titleds."')";
```

For example, your var `$filed` is an imploded array, which looks like `('foo'), ('bar')`. Finally, your request will looks like `INSERT INTO photo VALUE (null, '('foo'), ('bar')', [...]);`.

You must escape simple quotes in `$filed`, `$filed1`, `$hopid`, `$titleds`, but I'm pretty sure your request is totally wrong.

Can you give us the `photo` table <strike>schema</strike> structure please ?

EDIT :

structure given : `(photo_id,ne_photo_image,fe_photo_image,hop_id,title)`

To insert multiple rows in a table, you must use this kind of syntax :

```
INSERT INTO photo(`photo_id`, `ne_photo_image`, `fe_photo_image`, `hop_id`, `title`)
VALUES
    (null, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux'),
    (null, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux'),
    (null, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux');
```

Aka, you must insert your datas **row by row**, not column by column (what you're trying to attempt right now).

Your code should looks like this (this is definitely not a full piece of code, I'm not sure to understand all your code, then I give you some track) :

```
<?php 
   $hopid = $_POST['photo_hop_id'];

   $titles = $_POST['photo_name_id'];
   $ne_photo_images = $_FILES['ne_photo_image']['tmp_name'];
   $fe_photo_images = $_FILES['fe_photo_image']['tmp_name'];

   /*
   I assume $titles, $ne_photo_images and $fe_photo_images 
   have the same number of elements, in the right order.
   */

   $sql = "INSERT INTO photo(`photo_id`, `ne_photo_image`, `fe_photo_image`, `hop_id`,    `title`) VALUES";
   for($i = 0, $l = sizeof($titles) ; $i < $l ; $i++)
   {
      //adding row datas
      $sql .= " (null, 
                 '".$ne_photo_images [$i]."', 
                 '".$fe_photo_images [$i]."', 
                 '".$hopid."', 
                 '".$titles[$i]."')";
      if($i < $l - 1)
         $sql .= ",";
   }

   if(mysql_query($sql))
      //get happy
   else
      //take a coffee
?>
```

Again, this code is far from perfect, I'm just trying to explain you how to approach the problem.

Comment: do you mean the table structure ?   (photo_id,ne_photo_image,fe_photo_image,hop_id,title)

Answer (score 0):

Remove apostrophes around `$filed`, `$filed1`, `$titleds`

```
$y = "INSERT INTO photo VALUES (null, ".$filed.", ".$filed1.", '".$hopid."', ".$titleds.")";
```

Never use `mysql_*` functions since its deprecated.

Comment: i try that and i get this : ArrayArrayColumn count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Dont post only error messages, post some useful debug info. Your resulting query for example

Comment: i got this result in my database : 18 (') (') 0 Nothing

Comment: @MeijuNainggolan post your full query. It should be like `INSERT INTO photo VALUES (NULL, 'image.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 2, 'title')`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are assigning submitted data to respective variables. And you are checking whether these variables are arrays. If not, you are assigning that variable with `array()`. So you are trying to convert it to an array variable with no elements, because when you do that assignment, you are overwriting any existing values.

So at the end, you might not have any elements in the arrays for the insertion, if your submitted data are not arrays!

For testing:

```
$abc = 'hi';
if(!is_array($abc))
{
    $abc = array();
}
print_r($abc); // $abc will be an empty array
```

Also, read what samsam and Alexander had pointed out about the single quotes.

Another thing is, `$_POST` is an associative array. And you have to pass in the `key` as string. In your first line : `$hopid = $_POST[photo_hop_id];`, it should be like this: `$hopid = $_POST['photo_hop_id'];`

When you want to echo a variable's value, you could simply do it like this: `echo $variblename;`. In your code: `<?echo "$dpm1[0]"?>`, it is better to use it like this: `<?echo $dpm1[0]?>` (ie, without the double quotes, as there is no other string inside it).

Comment: thanks for the feedback man... i am really sorry for the spot :)